# Changing hyperlink on refresh

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails

How to put just one random link(out of many) on page every time a user reloads the page?

e.g

```
 <a href="https://google.com">link 1</a>
 <a href="https://stackoverflow.com">link 2</a>
 ...
```

or in rails

```
<%= link_to "link 1", "https://google.com" %>
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just use some rand value, for example

```
/*view.html.erb*/
<% var ||= rand(2) %>
<%= link_to_if var == 0, "http://www.google.com" %>
<%= link_to_if var == 1, "http://www.facebook.com" %>
```

you can set this into a partial, or maybe an array in your controller a call the array with de rand value like

```
<%= link_to @array_of_links[var] %>
```

or if you want to save this into your db you can just pick a random record with

```
/*controller*/
@link = Link.order("RANDOM()").first
```

because of MVC flow it will get a random value each time, regards